# Android - Regex to filter credit/debit card transactions

Tags: android, regex, mobile

I'm trying to find all the credit/debit card transaction sms. First I'm storing all the messages into list then running a loop through it and performing an following regex to find all the messages that contains 16 digit card number

**([0-9]*[Xx*]*[0-9])**

But from the above regex i'm getting card transaction message along with promotional messages also. Is there any way to filter only card transaction messages?

Answer (score 0):

This Regex captures a 16 digit long credit Card number:

```
(x|X|\d){16}
```

Comment: in transaction messages 16digits debit/credit card number will not come. It will be either 123xx1234 or only xxx1234 like that

Comment: but those numbers aren't 16 digits long

Comment: Yes they are not 16 digits. I used one regular expression ([0-9]*[Xx\\*]*[0-9]*[Xx\\*]+[9-3]{3,}^|[iI][nN][rR]\\.?\\s*   but this one not returning 100% banking transactions